Any Scripts for Generating ISO Squashfs Layers
I am builing my 22.04 livecd: add more tools (lsscsi, ipmitool, etc...) after finish install system and in livecd.
I check the doc LiveCDCustomization and LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch, I notice there are some different with the doc: In LiveCDCustomization it only say one layer named filesystem.squashfs in the dir /casper, but I found FOUR layers in /casper ubuntu-server-minimal.squashfs  ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.squashfs  ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.squashfs  ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.squashfs, and they have different usage for the installing the system.
I think I need to change the layer named ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.squashfs, and update ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.squashfs, ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.squashfs to keep everything is right.
The doc not update about it, and not say anything to pack them, I think these layer is depends on last layers, and just like /var/lib/dpkg/status and ld-cache it will depends info on previous layers.
I can't just install tool when I setup system, because I need use the livecd to check the problem.
Is there anyone known how to repack for different layer squashfs?

If this comment is more info for the question please edit the question and add the info, not as a comment.

just stopped to answer this as I have been working on similar.
https://github.com/michaeltandy/ubuntu-desktop-22.04-autoinstall/
As well, this was created by what I would call "the subiquity guy".
https://github.com/mwhudson/livefs-editor
Other helpful info
https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/overlayfs.html
https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/config.html?highlight=sources
